# value is pasted twice in column

Tags: excel, date, userform, vba

My problem is with column "A". In this column today's date should be pasted in first blank row. However I get it pasted twice. 1st time when UserForm1 is shown and second time when I click CommandButton1. Everything else works fine (data from UserForm1 is pasted into last row + 1. Issue is only with column "A".
Please find the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Call UserForm_Initialize

Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

'UserForm1.Label9.Caption = ws.Range("A1").Value

Set ws = Sheets("Log")

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Quality"
    .AddItem "Time"
    .AddItem "Money"
End With


LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'ostatni wiersz


'entry date
    ws.Range("A1").Copy
       Sheets("Log").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'pasting data from form
'ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Label9.Caption
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox8.Text
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = TextBox3.Text
ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = TextBox4.Text
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBox5.Text
ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text
ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = TextBox6.Text
ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = TextBox7.Text
End Sub
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserForm_Initialize()` executes every time you open the userform. So you are executing the whole code from `UserForm_Initialize()` every time when this user form is shown, and then when you are clicking the `CommandButton1`. You see a problem only in column A, because every TextBox is empty, so your program fills rest cells with nothing. The solution here would be separate the part of code initializing Userform and the part that copy values to cells. You can do it like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopyToCells
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Quality"
        .AddItem "Time"
        .AddItem "Money"
    End With
End Sub

Sub CopyToCells()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Log")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'ostatni wiersz

    'entry date
    ws.Range("A1").Copy
    Sheets("Log").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'pasting data from form
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox8.Text
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = TextBox3.Text
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = TextBox4.Text
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBox5.Text
    ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text
    ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value = TextBox6.Text
    ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = TextBox7.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed information. Now I understand how it all communicated with one another and why it resulted in such a way. You're great!

Comment: No problem, pozdrowienia z Poznania ;)